# how to play audio from python on Raspbian Stretch Lite?

Tags: audio, raspbian-stretch

I would like to play selected audio files through the built-in audio port on a Raspberry 3 that is running Raspbian Stretch Lite, from a python program. Unfortunately, none of the libraries or external applications that I have tried for this purpose work.

> sudo pip install pygame

results in

> Unable to run "sdl-config". Please make sure a development version of
>   SDL is installed.

and

> pip install sdl

fails with

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sdl (from
>   versions: ) No matching distribution found for sdl

mplayer won’t install.

mpg321 comes closest, installing but then failing when used, with ALSA lib errors, and you can’t install a new version of alas-utils because

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement alsa-utils
>   (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for alsa-utils

What do people do to play music on this OS?

Comment: I installed pygame using the command: "$ sudo pip install pygame" without any problem.  I got the message "Requirement also satisfied, ...", I am using Rpi3B+ stretch 9 (regular version, not lite version).

Comment: I also tried to import the pygame module in a python program and run the demo code of analog/digital clock and found everything OK ( https://www.pygame.org/project/994 ). I have not yet try any audio player though.

Comment: related (if not dupe): https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/94098/19949

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just tested it with two favorite programs: **omxplayer** and **mpv**. I used a fresh flashed up to date [Raspbian Buster Lite](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) but it shouldn't make a difference to Raspbian Stretch Lite. Playing music with this programs works out of the box without an modifications.

For testing first I plugged in a simple earphone into the analog audio output plug of my Raspberry Pi 4B. Then downloaded a test **mp3** file from [Sample .mp3 download](https://file-examples.com/index.php/sample-audio-files/sample-mp3-download/). I selected the smallest one:

```
rpi ~$ curl https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3 > file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3
```

Then installed **omxplayer**:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt install omxplayer
```

and played the test file:

```
rpi ~$ omxplayer file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3
```

Same with **mpv**:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt install mpv
rpi ~$ mpv file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3
```

I would prefer **omxplayer** because it is lighter than **mpv** and explicitly supports the hardware acceleration of the Raspberry Pi.

Now play it from python3:

```
rpi ~$ python3
Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr  3 2019, 05:39:12) 
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.system('/usr/bin/omxplayer /home/pi/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3')
```

or playing it in the background:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/omxplayer', '/home/pi/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3'])
exit()
rpi ~$    # exit from python3 but still playing
```

You may have a look at an omxplayer-wrapper. Look at google with `python omxplayer-wrapper`.

Answer (score 0):

How to play audio in Python3 on RaspiOS Bullseye lite (I'd recommend to use the current version) - because VLC supports many audio formats, I use this library.

Install pulseaudio:

```
sudo apt install alsa-oss libasound2-plugins libavresample4 pulseaudio pulseaudio-utils
```

Start server:

```
pulseaudio -D
```

You can display your audio sinks (outputs) with:

```
pacmd list-sinks
```

Playing is possible with pacmd as well but only WAV:

```
pacmd play-file  <path> <sinkno>
```

You have to specify the full, absolute path for the file.

Troubleshooting for pulseaudio:

Stopping server:

```
systemctl --user stop pulseaudio.socket
systemctl --user stop pulseaudio.service
```

Starting server interactively for output to screen:

```
pulseaudio -v
```

VLC:
Install necessary parts of VLC:

```
sudo apt install vlc-bin vlc-plugin-base
```

Install VLC library for Python:

```
sudo pip install python-vlc
```

In Python:

```
import vlc
p = vlc.MediaPlayer("<audiofile>")
p.play()
```

Volume can be got and set with:

```
vlc.libvlc_audio_get_volume(p)
vlc.libvlc_audio_set_volume(p,50)
```

I hope this answer is helpful.

Additional hint: If you plug in your USB device, this device should be the default for audio output.