# Play multiple mp3 files

Tags: python, audio-playback

I need to be able to play up to 8 mp3 files at the same time.  Is this possible with the raspberry pi 3b+? They need to be started in python code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my answer [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/94207/19949):

The test is done on a Pi Zero with a recent Raspbian, Python 3.6, `vlc` (along with approx. 150 other packages), and it's Python-bindings. It's using a USB soundcard and `alsa`.

Playing from Python worked straight forward:

```
import vlc
instance = vlc.Instance('--aout=alsa')
p = instance.media_player_new()
m = instance.media_new('something.mp3') 
p.set_media(m)
p.play() 
p.pause() 
vlc.libvlc_audio_set_volume(p, volume)  # volume 0..100
```

I was able to run four independent mp3's from a single Python process with a CPU load of about 87%. Starting a fifth player resulted in this error:

```
alsa audio output error: cannot estimate delay: Broken pipe
```

Given the more powerful CPU of the Pi 3B+ and its four cores I dare say it'll work. Use `multiprocessing` though to allow for the distribution of the load to more than one core.

---

Further reading:

- [LibVLC](https://wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC)
- [API documentation of module vlc](https://www.olivieraubert.net/vlc/python-ctypes/doc/)

Comment: I need the option of also playing each on a loop, so you have the command for that? What usb sound card are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a simple issue of running the mpg123 command multiple times.

```
sudo apt-get install mpg123
man mpg123
```

If you want it in python

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['mpg123','<your options>'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea, why not you use Python to play sound. Here is some code:
Before the code, you will need [this library](https://pypi.org/project/simpleaudio/) installed in your project.

```
# Import the library, and have it installed in your project
import simpleaudio


# Variables
sound_1 = './sounds/correct.wav'
sound_2 = './sounds/correct.wav'


# Use this function in your code to play sound
def playsound(directory):
    play = simpleaudio.WaveObject.from_wave_file(directory)
    play.play()


# Play the sound and wait for the sound to stop playing before continuing with the code
def playsound_wait(directory):
    play = simpleaudio.WaveObject.from_wave_file(directory)
    play.play().wait_done()


# Run the code below to play the sound (I used the sound_1 and sound_2 variable)
playsound(sound_1)
playsound_wait(sound_2)
```

Hope this makes it simple